# Powershell stuck when regex matching

Tags: powershell

I really don't understand why powershell stuck at this line when I'm matching a regex.

```
$failedlist = [regex]::Matches((Get-Content -Path log.txt -raw),"(?m)^-+(?:\r?\n(?!-|Input #\d).*)*\r?\nInput #(?<number>\d+).*?from '(?<filename>[^'\r\n]+)':(?:\r?\n(?!-).*)*\r?\n[Ff]ailed to")
```

and here's `log.txt`:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\output\123.mp4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\users\somefolder\123.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41mp423gp5
    date            : 2013-04-20T09:00:01+1000
    encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
  Duration: 00:04:51.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 931 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 864x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5], 802 kb/s, 24.51 fps, 24.51 tbr, 12257 tbn, 49.03 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 75 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-29T15:28:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC MPEG-4 OD Handler
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-29T15:28:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC MPEG-4 Scene Description Handler
    Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 39 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-29T15:28:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Hint Handler
    Stream #0:5(und): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 7 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-29T15:28:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Hint Handler
avcuvid: --sub-copy/--vpp-subburn is set, but no subtitle stream found.
Max B frames are 0 frames.
NVEncC (x64) 5.01 (r1507) by rigaya, May  7 2020 12:04:16 (VC 1916/Win/avx2)
OS Version     Windows 10 x64 (18363)
CPU            Intel Core i7-7700HQ @ 2.80GHz [TB: 3.49GHz] (4C/8T)
GPU            #0: GeForce GTX 1080 with Max-Q Design (2560 cores, 1468 MHz)[PCIe3x16][442.19]
NVENC / CUDA   NVENC API 9.1, CUDA 10.2, schedule mode: auto
Input Buffers  CUDA, 17 frames
Input Info     avcuvid: H.264/AVC, 864x480, 25/1 fps
Vpp Filters    cspconv(nv12 -> p010)
Output Info    H.265/HEVC main10 @ Level auto
               864x480p 1:1 25.000fps (25/1fps)
               avwriter: hevc, aac => mp4
Encoder Preset default
Rate Control   CQP  I:23  P:23  B:23
Lookahead      off
GOP length     250 frames
B frames       0 frames [ref mode: disabled]
Ref frames     3 frames
AQ             off
CU max / min   auto / auto
Others         mv:auto 
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\Done\123.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoding_tool   : NVEncC (x64) 5.01
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(progressive), 864x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 12800 tbn (default)
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 75 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp4 @ 00000271e1ac5340] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file

encoded 7154 frames, 1251.79 fps, 1080.82 kbps, 36.87 MB
encode time 0:00:05, CPU: 13.4%, GPU: 13.9%, VE: 80.1%, VD: 42.6%, GPUClock: 1648MHz, VEClock: 1479MHz
frame type IDR   29
frame type I     29,  avgQP  23.00,  total size   0.25 MB
frame type P   7125,  avgQP  23.00,  total size  36.62 MB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\output\456.mp4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[wmv3 @ 0000015b661b7a80] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Input #0, asf, from 'C:\Users\users\somefolder\456.mp4':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: M1
    WM/WMADRCPeakReference: 32767
    WM/WMADRCPeakTarget: 32767
    WM/WMADRCAverageReference: 6067
    WM/WMADRCAverageTarget: 6067
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6000.6346
    IsVBR           : 0
  Duration: 00:29:48.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2628 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 720x480, 2500 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: wmapro (b[1][0][0] / 0x0162), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
avcuvid: --sub-copy/--vpp-subburn is set, but no subtitle stream found.
avcuvid: codec wmv3(yuv420p) unable to decode by cuvid.
failed to initialize file reader(s).
Failed to open input file.
```

The log consist of two video conversion log, separated by the continuous dash line. The regex will find any failed conversion video from the log, and put them into `filename` and `number` column. In this case `456.mp4` is the failed one. However if `log.txt` didn't consist the log of `123.mp4`, powershell will not stuck at that line of code. Any idea why?

**EDIT:**

It seems like without the `-raw` flag, it's not stuck, but it won't match any.

Comment: Please show your desired output aswell

Comment: The output is similar to this: https://regex101.com/r/SPYMrA/1
And I found out that at the end of the regex, if I add `.*\r?\n`, powershell works as expected. This is the fully working regex `(?m)^-+(?:\r?\n(?!-|Input #\d).*)*\r?\nInput #(?<number>\d+).*?from '(?<filename>[^'\r\n]+)':(?>\r?\n(?!-).*)*\r?\nfailed to.*\r?\n`. I wonder why.